# How To Determine First Time Logged In Java Web App?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have a Java web application I am building and I want a simple way to check and see if when a user reaches a page; that it is the first page on login (or to put it another way, that it is the first time logged in) for that session.

Any tricks or simple ways to do this? Either in the JSP or in the Servlet.

Comment: Wouldn't you have a new session each time the user logs in?

Comment: Have you lookinto Spring Security? It has that exact functionality.

Comment: @Gedalya What did you mean with: *for that session*?

Comment: The context was the time in which a user is logged into the application; new on login and closed on logout.

Comment: Its not at all clear what you're asking, and there's no effort (which would clarify the goal probably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. There is several ways to do that, if I don't misunderstand. You want to know if this is the first time the user logs into the system. You can determine it using:

- A database:

  ```
  username password first_time
  -------- -------- -----------
  admin    123      NO
  newuser  pass     YES
  ```
- A cookie

  > A cookie is the perfect way to differentiate first-timers from repeat visitors. Check
  >   for the existence of a uniquely named cookie; if it is there, the client is a repeat 
  >   visitor. If the cookie is not there, the visitor is a newcomer, and you should set an 
  >   outgoing "this user has been here before" cookie.

  From the book [*Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages*](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/). See Chapter 8: *Handling 
  Cookies* for a full example.